# Replace regex-matched word with modified version of the word

Tags: regex, sed, replace, pattern-matching, match

I am trying to replace a 10-digit number I find with regex, with the same word pre-pended with "abc". For example, if the matched number is 0123456789, I want to replace that word with abc0123456789 instead.

Googling around, I found that sed is useful for replacing words in a file -

```
sed -i '' -e 's/[0-9]\{10\}/new-word/g' *.csv
```

This command successfully replaced my 10-digit number instances with "new_word". How do I instead replace it with "abc + [matched word]"
?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use parentheses to create a "matching capture group". To refer to the first group, use `\1`, and so on:

```
s/\([0-9]\{10\}\)/abc\1/g
```

Or use `&` which stands for "the whole matching part":

```
s/[0-9]\{10\}/abc&/g
```